# How to get initial link for iOS using react native firebase dynamic links?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I am using react-native-firebase:: 5.6.0, I am having issue while getting initial link for iOS device. On android it's working fine. I am using "Firebase Dynamic Links" to redirect user inside login screen of my app if in case he is not logged in inside app, otherwise just opening app if he is already logged in.
It's working for android app but having an issue with ios app. I have used two function one is the get dynamic link if app is closed "getInitialLink" and another one is to check when app is opened "onLink".

This is function I am using after closing splash screen, only called once when opening app from closing state.

```
firebase.links().getInitialLink().then((url) => {
    if (url && url === 'https://mycustomdomain.co.in') {
        navigationToScreen(AUTH, INITIAL_SCREEN);
    } else {
        // INITIALIZE APP HERE
    }
});
```

If app already opened I am getting dynamic link  url value inside this function::

```
this.unsubscribeHandleOpenAppDynamicLinks = firebase.links().onLink(async (url) => {
    let isLoggedIn = await AsyncStorage.getItem(LocalStorageKeys.IS_LOGGEDIN);
    if (url) {
        if ( isLoggedIn !== 'yes' && url === 'https://mycustomdomain.co.in') {
            navigationToScreen(AUTH, INITIAL_SCREEN);
        }
    }
});


and clearing that listener on componentWillUnmount:: this.unsubscribeHandleOpenAppDynamicLinks();
```

> In case of iOS only "onLink" function is working and I am
>   getting url value as "undefined".  getInitialLink() function will
>   returns the URL that the app has been launched from. If the app was
>   not launched from a URL the return value will be null, but I am
>   getting "undefined" even when launching an app from url in case of iOS
>   only. I am getting url inside onLink() in case of iOS when app is
>   launched. Why this is happening??

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I am having similar problems. I noticed that Linking.getInitialURL works. Been cursing react-native-firebase for the last hour or so.

Comment: @vijayst Have you figured out anything? I started to look at getInitialURL but the URL it returns is not as clean the RNF returns from onLink

Comment: yes, I found a solution. But, it is too long to write it in a comment. I took the shortened link that I got and passed it to a native module which I wrote - which uses Firebase SDK resolveShortLink function. That returns the deep link that you want in your app.

Comment: @alittletf I made the native code available in this article: https://vijayt.com/post/dynamic-links-module-of-react-native-firebase-not-working-well-with-expo/

Answer (score 2):

If `getInitialLink` method does not work, it is either because of improper linking or due to Expo runtime. As an alternative, use `Linking.getInitialURL` method to get the initial URL. This requires a little bit of native code as well. This is because Linking module does not know how to interpret the shortened URL. So, we call the `resolveShortLink` method of Firebase SDK to get the embedded deep link. Once we receive the embedded deep link, we can handle it as usual in our app.

The native source code is documented in this [article](https://vijayt.com/post/dynamic-links-module-of-react-native-firebase-not-working-well-with-expo/). But for completeness, I will post it here.

```
#import "FDLResolver.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation FDLResolver

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(resolveShortLink:(NSString *)shortLink :(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
    :(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    id completion = ^(NSURL *_Nullable dynamicLink, NSError *_Nullable error) {
      if (!error && dynamicLink) {
        resolve(dynamicLink.absoluteString);
      } else {
          reject(@"Error", @"Error in getting dynamic link", error);
      }
    };

    NSURL *shortLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:shortLink];
    [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] resolveShortLink:shortLinkURL completion:completion];
}

@end
```

And Linking module code is below.

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
  if (url && url.includes('page.link')) {
    const shortLink = url.replace('exps', 'https')
    NativeModules.FDLResolver.resolveShortLink(shortLink)
      .then(link => {
        const linkParts = link.split('?')
        const query = qs.parse(linkParts[1])
        this.parseRouteUrl(query.deep_link_id)
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: Hey @vijayst thank you for taking the time to write a blog post on this. Unfortunately I am getting an error. I followed your directions exactly. I keep getting "Unhandled promise rejection. Type Error: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.FDLResolver.resolveShortLink'). Any isead what could be wrong? Also what is the significance of replace https with exps?

Comment: You will have to add FDLResolver.h and FDLResolver.m into your Xcode project (just like you would do with any native module)

Comment: can you be a little more descriptive? I've never added a native module before. I've placed my FDLResolver.h and FDLResolver.m files in my /ios/myproj folder where my AppDelegate files are. Are you saying I need to import the FDLResolver.h files into my AppDelegate.m file like this ---> "#import "FDLResolver.h" ?

Comment: I was able to get things working! I use webstorm for development and while I had created the files in the right directory I noticed they didnt show up in Xcode. I added the files to xcode and things work smooth now. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @alittletf - I wrote a follow-up article where I got getInitialLink to work - https://vijayt.com/post/testing-dynamic-links-and-fixing-react-native-firebase-issues/

Comment: @vijayst I can't thank you enough for taking the time to share your solution, it works wonderfully. This is exactly what I was looking for. You saved me many hours of work.